# Google API for Play Console, is it possible to check if app is "in-review"?

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I have some automation built around the Google Play Console rollout feature, it does check roll-out value and informs about it on some Slack channel but also it bumps up rollout value up if stability is sufficient.

However, from time to time Google review process is taking not hours but days and when it happens all those automations are running with the assumption that the app is verified because Google API is returning rollout value even if application is in review - I don't mind this behaviour but at the same time I am not able to find any endpoint to see if the application is still in review and, in such case, stop my automations.

Is there some magic endpoint to do that or am I forced to web scrap that value?

Comment: Hello, would you share what you already automated so far? I'm struggling to automate info like review status changing to a Slack channel. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nothing more except things I already mentioned, there is still no way of telling if app is in review or not, which is a bummer